# How can I customize Search Result in SXA?

Tags: content-search, sxa

Out of the box SXA `Search Results` component shows only page `Title`.

How can I customize that component to show page `Image` and `Description`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use **Rendering variants** for this.

When you edit the search results rendering properties, there is a field which allows you to select rendering variant. You can choose from the couple of default ones but you can define your own.

In order to define a variant you have to:

1. Insert new `Variant definition` in the `Presentation\Rendering Variants\Search results`
2. Insert two child items of type `Field` and name them `Image` and `Description` (actually you can name them whatever you want but the name is propagated to **Field** field which is used to identify which field should be used to get the data from)

You can read more in the [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/renderings/create_a_rendering_variant)

[Here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/building_the_layout/renderings/the_sxa_renderings_and_rendering_variants) is the list of SXA renderings with information which of them supports component variants

Comment: Hello Szymon:) In SXA we have renamed the Component Variants into Rendering Variants.